# OnItemClickListener of spinner

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-spinner

I am able to get Spinner in action bar this way;
array of items in re/values/languages.xml

```
 <string-array name="languages">
    <item>Finnish</item>
    <item>French</item>
    <item>German</item>
    <item>Slovakian</item>
    <item>Polish</item>
</string-array>
```

In res/menu/main.xml

```
  <item
    android:id="@+id/menuSort"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/spinner"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/choose"/>
```

In res/layout/spinner.xml

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:entries="@array/languages"/>
```

And finally activity class;

```
 public class Base_Activity extends Activity {

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
    Log.i("DEBUG1", "CHECKPOINT1");
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    Log.i("DEBUG2", "CHECKPOINT2");
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(0);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

               String items=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
               Log.i("Selected item : ",items);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
    return true;
}
```

}

What I am not getting is on ItemSelected of spinner items nothing happens. As you can see from my xml file that I do not even need Adapter to get the spinner. But I am using adapter to so something to get OnItemSelected. Please help me what has happened here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try this may helps you

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) menu.getItem(0).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                String items = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Log.i("Selected item : ", items);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }

        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: gives {java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner}

Comment: Now the strings(items) are missing from spinner.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct but I edited a bit to reach my goal.

Comment: Great arguments names arg0, arg1, arg2 and arg3. Very readable! Maybe you should add the Android sourcecode to eclipse or start using Android Studio.

Comment: I like the example. For some reason, the spinners guide on Android doesn't stress spinner.getSelectedItem(). They recomment you use arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2): http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `OnItemClickListener` and not `OnItemSelectedListener` if you want the click event.

Your method will only work if you select your items or browse through the view using a trackball or up/down arrows. If you want click, then add `OnItemClickListener` and override

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3)
```

Comment: Tried that also but did not help. :(

Comment: Done now!! check the ticked answer. Thanks for the support.

Comment: spinner with OnItemClickListener is returing Runtime Exception that it cannot be used together. It looks like you should use onItemSelectedListener.